# Merge 3 rows that have json value

Tags: php, arrays, json, codeigniter

I have in a database table 3 rows that are `json` data and i want them merge they in a array, how can fix it?

**Row 1 :** ["11,22,13"]
**Row 2 :** ["48"]
**Row 3 :** ["53,67,70"]

**I want in output as: `array(11,22,13,48,53,67,70)`**

My tried as:

```
$result = $this->db->get_where('table',array('mainpage'=>$mp'));
    $data = array();
    foreach($result->result() as $row){
        $dv = json_decode($row->sbouy);
        $out = array();
        foreach($dv as $idx => $val){
            $out[] = $val;
        }
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($out); // This is not what I want output
    }
```

In my code output is as(This is not what I want output):

```
Array
(
    [0] => 11,22,13
)
Array
(
    [0] => 48
)
Array
(
    [0] => 53,67,70
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
    $data = array();
    $out = array();
    foreach($result->result() as $row){
        $dv = json_decode($row->sbouy);

        foreach($dv as $idx => $val){
            $out[] = $val;
        }

    }
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($out); // This is what you want :)
```

You have to define `$out` outside foreach. Instead of loop you can even use [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

Comment: How can use of array_merge, Please tell a example? I want in output as: array(11,22,13,48,53,67,70)

Comment: $out = array_merge($dv, $out);use this instead of looping

Comment: but i have in output as : `Array
(
    [0] => 53,67,70
    [1] => 48
    [2] => 11,22,13
);` my php code is as: `foreach($result->result() as $row){
      $dv = json_decode($row->subpage);
      $out = array_merge($dv, $out);
  }` I want in output as: array(11,22,13,48,53,67,70) How can fix it?